# Finding probability function different to every single associated probability function in (N, P(N))

Tags: probability, natural-numbers

Okay so I have the following problem: Let P be some probability function such that (N,P(N)) is a probability space with said function, with P(N) being parts of N. Find a probability function Q in (N, P(N)), such that Q $\neq$ $P_X$ for every random variable X: N $\to$ N given.

I'm trying something similar to the diagonalization argument that proofs the rationals are not numerable using decimal expansion. Namely, if I enumerate every random variable as $X_n$, creating a new random variable that sends n to $X_n(n)+1$. Then I "assume" that the associated probability function $P_X$ is different to every ${P_X}_n$. Problem is this only demonstrates that the set of random variables X: N $\to$ N is not countable.

Comment: What do you mean by "a random probability function in (N, P(N))"?  Please define your terms.  Is  N supposed to be $\mathbb N$?  The set of natural numbers?  Something else?

Comment: Sorry. I meant some probability function P such that (N, P(N)) is a probability space with said function. P(N) is parts of N

Comment: What's a "probability function"?  What are "parts of N"?  What is $P_X$?  I think that if you clearly write out what you mean, the desired result will be easier for you to prove (or disprove).

Comment: A probability function is a probability function. Refer to a basic course in Probability for its meaning. As for N I think it is clear it's the natural numbers. $P_X$ is the associated probability function for the random variable X.

Comment: Rationals are not numerable ? Never heard of that.

Comment: @abrea02 Is $(\mathbb N,\mathcal P(\mathbb N),P)$ a probability space in this context? This with $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ as powerset? If so then $P$ is a probability *measure*. The term "probability function" is vague. Sometimes it is meant to be "probability density function", another time a "probability mass function" and again another time a "cumulative distribution function". Make yourself more clear please (basic courses do not help on this).